# django 1.4 with apache virtualhost - path problems

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to upgrade my application from django 1.2 to 1.4, which I have tested successfully with the inbuilt webserver.

However, I am having problems with deploying it as a VirtualHost with Apache (on Ubuntu).

my `sites-available/default` contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapplication

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/myapplication/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapplication python-path=/usr/share/myapplication:/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages

    <Directory /usr/share/myapplication>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

the file `/usr/share/myapplication/wsgi.py` contains the standard:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapplication.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache will start ok, but when I go to `http://myapplication` I get '500: Internal Server Error' and the apache logs show:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'WCReporter.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named WCReporter.settings
```

Am I using WSGIDaemonProcess correctly? The django docs aren't clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this with the following, from http://rc98.net/django_wsgi.

sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapplication

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapplication
    WSGIProcessGroup myapplication

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/myapplication/wsgi.py
    <Directory /usr/share/myapplication>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and wsgi.py:

```
import os,sys

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = '/usr/share/myapplication'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapplication.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you print your path at runtime:

```
#init.py

    import sys
    print sys.path
```

1. have you got an init file in the project base dir?
2. does it work if you import settings instead of myapp.settings?

Comment: 1. yes myapp/__init.py__ exists, 2. no, same error. Do you mean I should add those lines to myapp/__init.py__? Where would I find the output?

Comment: path includes ['/usr/share/myapplication','/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',  '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/share/myapplication/..']

Comment: no, just dist-packages where it resides. Shall I add it explicitly to the WSGIDaemonProcess paths?

Comment: I have done this, and when running ./manage.py runserver, it does not appear in the path list! So something is clearly wrong with my WSGIDaemonProcess line

Comment: That's helped, have added complete answer. Thanks!